# Можно ли переключаться между getchar() и getwchar()?

Tags: c, linux

При попытке чтения символов сначала функцией `getchar()` а потом `getwchar()` (или наоборот - сначала `getwchar()` а потом `getchar()`) вторая функция возвращает EOF.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <locale.h>

main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  printf ("locale: %s\n",setlocale(LC_ALL,""));

  int    c1 = 5, c2 = 6;
  wint_t wc1 = 998, wc2 = 999;
  int fd;

  errno = 10000;
  if (av[1]) {
    printf ("getchar()...getwchar()\n");
    c1 = getchar();
    c2 = getchar();
    // freopen("/dev/tty","r",stdin);
    //    fd = dup(0);
    //    fclose(stdin);
    //    stdin = fdopen(dup2(fd,0),"r");
    //    clearerr(stdin);
    //    fflush(stdin);
    wc1 = getwchar();
    wc2 = getwchar();
  } else {
    printf ("getwchar()...getchar()\n");
    wc1 = getwchar();
    wc2 = getwchar();
    // freopen("/dev/tty","r",stdin);
    //    fd = dup(0);
    //    fclose(stdin);
    //    stdin = fdopen(dup2(fd,0),"r");
    //    clearerr(stdin);
    //    fflush(stdin);
    c1 = getchar();
    c2 = getchar();
  }

  printf ("errno = %d [%m]\n",errno);
  printf ("c1=%x c2=%x wc1=%x wc2=%x\n",c1,c2,wc1,wc2);
}

avp@avp-xub11:~/src/ig/web-agent$ ./a.out 
locale: ru_RU.UTF-8
getwchar()...getchar()
1234
errno = 29 [Недопустимая операция смещения]
c1=ffffffff c2=ffffffff wc1=31 wc2=32
avp@avp-xub11:~/src/ig/web-agent$
```

От наличия вызова `setlocale()` ситуация (принципиально) не меняется. Из всех придуманных мной попыток наладить переключение, удается только freopen(), но это не может быть нормальным решением проблемы, т.к. уже буферизованные данные пропадают.

В windows проблема не наблюдается, но там другая (однобайтная) локализация: locale: Russian_Russia.1251

**Как решить данную задачу?**

Comment: Не пробовали `scanf( "%wc", ... )`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел кое-что **не обнадеживающее** в `man fwide`

```
   if stream has no orientation yet; in this case the next
   I/O operation might change the orientation (to byte oriented if it is a
   char I/O operation, or to wide-character oriented if it is a wide-char‐
   acter I/O operation).

   Once  a  stream  has  an orientation, it cannot be changed and persists
   until the stream is closed.
```

Похоже проблема просто (без хаков структур из libio.h (пока не очень понятно в какой момент, сорсы libc надо читать)) не решается.

Или сделать свои аналоги семейства getwchar() ??? Или аналоги под другим именем ?

Пока вопрос не закрываю, жду советов.

---

**UPDATE**

Читать libio стало лень, написал свое. Может кому-нибудь пригодится. Если остальной код интересен, могу выложить куда-нибудь.

```
/*
  ucsutf.h  avp 2012

  Функции для UTF-8 и Unicode (ASCII&Cyrillic), независимые от setlocale()
 */

#ifndef UCSUTF_H
#define UCSUTF_H

#include <stdlib.h>

// возвращает ucs из utf-8 в памяти
extern int  utf8_to_ucs (const char *utf, int *step, int *err); 
// записать ucs в кодировке utf-8 в память, возвращает к-во записанных байт
extern int  ucs_to_utf8 (int uc, char *b);
// аналоги ctype для ucs (ascii & cyrillic)
extern int  isAlpha (int ucs);
extern int  isLower (int ucs);
extern int  isUpper (int ucs);
extern int  toLower (int ucs);
extern int  toUpper (int ucs);
// длина utf-8 символа (по первому байту)
extern int  utf8_chrlen (const char *utf);
// convert символ utf-8 в памяти (по месту), возвращают к-во  байт
extern int  utf8_toUpper (char *s, int *err);
extern int  utf8_toLower (char *s, int *err);


struct getucs {
  u_int  ucs,     // m.b. EOF 
    nc,  // прочитано из stream байт в bytes[] 
    err; // 0 if OK, при ошибке - err == nc
  char   bytes[8];
};

extern int  utf8_fgetc (struct getucs *uc, FILE *stream); // ucs из utf-8 stream
#endif
```

---

```
/*
  ucsutf.c  avp 2012

  Функции для UTF-8 и Unicode (ASCII&Cyrillic), независимые от setlocale()
 */


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include "ucsutf.h"

/*
  utf-8 схема                                               error: 0xFF, 0xFE
  1111 110x , 1111 10xx , 1111 0xxx , 1110 xxxx , 110x xxxx , 10xx xxxx
  10xx xxxx , 10xx xxxx , 10xx xxxx , 10xx xxxx , 10xx xxxx 
  10xx xxxx , 10xx xxxx , 10xx xxxx , 10xx xxxx
  10xx xxxx , 10xx xxxx , 10xx xxxx
  10xx xxxx , 10xx xxxx
  10xx xxxx
*/
// значимые биты из первого байта UTF-8
static int mask[5] = { 0x01, 0x03 ,0x07 ,0x0F ,0x1F};

/*
  Некая замена fgetwc() 
  не зависит от setlocale() и ПОЗВОЛЯЕТ использовать fgetc() и др. 

  Возвращает UCS from stream UTF-8 characters or EOF 
  если преобразование UTF-8 -> UCS невозможно возвращает EOF 
  и устанавливает errno в EILSEQ

  Также заполняет структуру getucs прочитанными байтами
*/

int
utf8_fgetc (struct getucs *uc, FILE *f)
{
  uc->nc = uc->err = 0;
  int c, n = 5;
  if (feof(f))
    c = EOF;
  else if ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
    uc->bytes[uc->nc++] = c;
    if (c > 127) {
      if ((c & 0xc0) == 0x80 || c == 0xff || c == 0xfe) {
        c = EOF;
        uc->err = 1;
      } else {
        while (n && (c & (1<<n)))
          n--;

        u_int ucs = c & mask[n-1];
        n = 6-n;
        while (n--) {
          if ((c = fgetc(f)) == EOF)
            break;
          if (((uc->bytes[uc->nc++] = c) & 0xc0) != 0x80) {
            uc->err = uc->nc;
            c = EOF;
            break;
          }
          ucs <<= 6;
          ucs |= (c & 0x3f);
        }
        if (c != EOF)
          c = ucs;
      }
    }
  }
  if (uc->err)
    errno = EILSEQ;
  return uc->ucs = c;
}
....
....
```